# Can't make nestednamespaces what are the best practices for django urls

Tags: python, django, url

I can't create nested namespaces like they are presented in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/ every time I go more than 1 level I lose all the other namespaces has anyone been successful with this and if so what are the best practices for django urls.

```
urlpatterns_3rd_level = patterns('example.basket.views', url(r'^3rd$', 'home', name='home'))
urlpatterns_2nd_level = patterns('', url(r'^2nd$', include(urlpatterns_3rd_level, namespace='basket')))

urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^1st$', include(urlpatterns_2nd_level, namespace='store')))

reverse('store:basket:home') # No namespace named basket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can go deeper because you're finishing the regex with the dollar sign `$`. When this happens, Python recognizes that as the end of the expression and stop matching anything that follow, this can either yield a `Url not found` or some other page you didn't requested.

Notice that every time they use `include` in the docs the regex doesn't have the `$` sign because normally you don't want to end the expression there but in the included urls.

Your example may work without the `$` signs like this:

```
urlpatterns_3rd_level = patterns('example.basket.views', url(r'^3rd$', 'home', name='home'))
urlpatterns_2nd_level = patterns('', url(r'^2nd', include(urlpatterns_3rd_level, namespace='basket')))

urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^1st', include(urlpatterns_2nd_level, namespace='store')))

reverse('store:basket:home') # No namespace named basket
```

**Hint:** Double check that `example.basket.views` is a valid module in your app because maybe the error may be that that module doesn't exist.

From the shell I tested this and it yield:

```
>>> '/1st2nd3rd'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're right I was have been doing this for so long I didn't even notice the $ at the end. And because most of the code is created using copy paste. Thanks for the solution.